# How to let two overlapping views to both receive the user input events?

Tags: android, view, touch

I would like to have two overlapping image views in my layout. But I need both of them to receive the user input event, such as touchDown, touchUp, pinch, etc. Could you give me some hints? Thanks

Comment: btw, my understanding is that only one of the two views could be in focus, so input events will be delivered to the one has focus, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an `onTouchListener` on both of the views. Then, get the bounds of both views (x and y location, width, height). When the onTouch method is fired, check to see which view was touched, then check to see if the x and y location of the touch falls within the bounds of the other view. If it does, then forward the touch event to the other view by doing:

`otherView.onTouch(motionEvent);`